# What the minimum edition of Windows 7 to work with Visual Studio/Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, windows-7, compatibility

With Windows Vista/XP, I needed at minimum the Home Premium edition. In the Home Basic edition of Vista/XP I cannot work with ASP.Net...

- What the minimum edition of Windows 7 to work with Visual Studio?
- What the minimum edition of Windows 7 to work with ASP.Net?

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser...

Comment: Visual Studio/Asp.net? are for programmers, not for just "superusers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any edition which supports Internet Information Services. Visual Studio is capable of operating on any Windows platform, but you need IIS in order to work on ASP.NET applications (Because they run on top of IIS).

According to [this page](http://digitizor.com/2009/02/20/how-to-install-microsoft-iis-server-on-windows-7/), IIS is available in Windows 7 editions "Professional" and above.

Comment: I found that page as well, but it's hardly the last word on the subject.

Comment: True -- but it's better than nothing. And the information is in line with the model used for Windows Vista, so it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The key ingredient is IIS, the web server used by ASP.Net.  It turned out to be harder than I expected to find which edition of Windows 7 you need to use IIS.  I wasn't able to find anything absolutely authoritative.  The closest I came was [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Install-Internet-Information-Services-IIS-7-5), which seems to indicate you can install it on *all* Windows 7 editions.  But that doesn't feel right to me so you might want to keep looking.